# Get GridPane consisting of ImageViews to fit in Margin of BorderPane and resizing

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a question concerning a Uni-project I'm working on.
We have to create a game, where we have a board that consists of tiles and you should be able to rotate these tiles with clicks. The Tiles should always fit in the Grid and the Grid should resize with the Window.

Now I made a class "TileView" which extends ImageView to get the pictures matching the pattern of the tile. Then I have TileGrid, which extends GridPane, which should consist of width*height tileviews. And this GridPane is in a BorderPane and this makes the scene.
Unfortunately I can't really put Code in here, because we have strict rules of plagiarism (and if someone sees my code and copies it, I'm going down too).

So, I make 2 for loops for the width and height and create a new TileView and set PreserveRatio on true and then do this:

```
setRowIndex(temp, i);
setColumnIndex(temp, j);
super.getChildren().add(temp);
```

this is in the class TileGrid.

Then I add it to the BorderPane with margin insets 100 and this is what happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JsxY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jsrM.jpg

But now I have the problem of fitting the TileViews to the size of the grid and make them resize with the window. I tried ("temp" is the just created ImageView as I put them in the TileGrid):

```
temp.fitWidthProperty().bind(prefWidthProperty());
temp.fitHeightProperty().bind(prefHeightProperty());
```

but then my single ImageViews are gigantic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkImb.jpg

This is filling my whole screen.

I've tried numerous things, searched for hours and never achieved what I wanted so I really hope someone can help me or give me a tip even without my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `SceneBuilder`?

Comment: No, I do it with code

Comment: Also, you should not share your whole code. You should create an MCVE.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know how I could do this without sharing my classes TileView and TileGrid, and as I said, there is the problem of plagiarism if one of my fellow students sees this.
I'm also pretty new to programming so I'm not that versed

Comment: you can do so by providing the problem you have on a smaller project with dummy naming classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a MCVE that demos what you need.

**Centers the GridPane content**

```
centerRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

**Binds the ImageViews fitHeight and fitWidth properties with the GridPanes height and width properties - 100(due to setMargins) / 10(the number of rows/columns)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
         Image image = new Image("https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png");
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
         imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(centerRoot.heightProperty().subtract(100).divide(10));
         imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(centerRoot.widthProperty().subtract(100).divide(10));
         imageView.setPreserveRatio(false);
         centerRoot.add(imageView, i, t);
     }
 }
```

> Full Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication241 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        GridPane centerRoot = new GridPane();
        centerRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(centerRoot, new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
        root.setCenter(centerRoot);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
                Image image = new Image("https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png");
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(centerRoot.heightProperty().subtract(100).divide(10));
                imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(centerRoot.widthProperty().subtract(100).divide(10));
                imageView.setPreserveRatio(false);
                centerRoot.add(imageView, i, t);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I still struggle with Javafx big time.
I implemented your suggestion in my classes, but the problem is, that it only works if I add the ImageViews after primaryStage.show();
But I have the for loops in my class TileGrid, so I invoke it where you wrote "GridPane centerRoot = new GridPane()"
which is "Board b = new Board(6, 6);
        TileGrid tg = new TileGrid(b);"
for me. 
I don't understand why your code example only works if the ImageViews are added after the show() method. Can you explain?

Comment: just a guess ->Before showing the `Stage`, the values for the bindings are zero. To test this, try changing the window size after load. The `GridPane` should look correct afterward.

Comment: Great, I finally got it working, thank you so so much!

Comment: @CatTheGrimReaper If the answer was successful in helping you, you should select it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't provide any code I'll try to give you steps to work with I hope it might help
First as the `BorderPane` and `GridPane` will adjust their sizes to the window you have one problem which is adjusting the sizes of the `ImageView`s to make it resizable you have to `bind` their sizes to the size of the scene and take into consideration the number of the rows and columns you wanted for the grid 
let's say you have 2 columns so image is 50% of the scene

```
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.getWidthProperty().divide(2));
```

Note: I'm not sure about the syntax of this line I kinda busy sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works better than before! 
Now the imageViews resize with the gridpane, but this happens:
https://imgur.com/a/Y7yqbnw
I guess it's because I preserve the ratio of the imageviews. Is there a possibility to preserve the ratio of the TileGrid or something like "always fit to children" or something like that?

Comment: you can do so by wrap the grid with a `GroupPane` it'll solve your problem but remember that the `BorderPane` match the parent size as well