# how can I bind gridview column count to window in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a dynamic gridview. I created a custom design for GridView items. But since the number of columns is static, the blank space increases when the window increases(sorry my english is bad)

default window size:

[image: default]

and how it looks when the screen is enlarged:

[image: large]

```
public void  initgrit( ){
    noBarcodes = new ArrayList<>(products());
    int col = 0;
    int row =0;
    for (ProductNoBarcode noBarcode: noBarcodes){
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/testView.fxml"));
            VBox vBox = fxmlLoader.load();
            testView testView1  = fxmlLoader.getController();
            testView1.setInfo(noBarcode);
            if (col == 3){
                 col=0;
                 ++row;
            }
            gridPane.add(vBox,col++,row);
            GridPane.setMargin(vBox,new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you change `GridPane`  to `Flowpane`

Comment: FlowPane works like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtNLB.gif)

Comment: `ControlsFX's` `GridView` might also be a viable option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968067/javafx-frozen-gui-when-adding-button-on-flow-panel/52973069#52973069

Comment: What should the enlarged window look like (what should be in the blank space)?  More carrots?

Comment: You could also try adding column constraints..
ColumnConstraints colThird = new ColumnConstraints();
colThird.setPercentWidth(33);
gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colThird,colThird,colThird);

Comment: please describe what you want to achieve _exactly_ .. a different layout (might be a FlowLayout as suggested by @GiovanniContreras ) might be the straightforward solution ..

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949913/get-gridpane-consisting-of-imageviews-to-fit-in-margin-of-borderpane-and-resizin/51950748#51950748)?